# Socket-io overdraw on collaborative canvas

Tags: node.js, reactjs, canvas, socket.io, collaboration

I am trying to build collaborative canvas with socket-io and with [react-canvas-draw](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-canvas-draw)
, but when I take a low opacity on brush-color, it just draws multiple circles on other screen, as shown here :
when I draw on one screen slowly, it just over draws on same location or something with many many circles,
[image: RESULT :]

**Drawing.js**

```
import DrawableCanvas from "react-canvas-draw";
import { Button } from "reactstrap";
import {SocketContext} from './context/socket';

const { Component } = require("react");
var canvas, context;

/* VARIABLES */
var drawing = false;
// determines the current x or y position
var current = {x: 0, y: 0};


export class Drawing extends Component {
  // this.context refers to socket.io making it available for all components
  static contextType = SocketContext;

  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
    this.state = {
      canvasWidth: 1400,
      canvasHeight: 1400,
      catenaryColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.68)",
      brushColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.68)",
      brushRadius: 1,
      lazyRadius: 0,
      clear: false,
      hideInterface: false,
      onChange: null,
      loadTimeOffset: 5,
      backgroundColor: "#FFF",
      hideGrid: false,
      disabled: false,
      saveData: "",
      immediateLoading: true,
      usingType: "draw",
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    canvas = document.getElementsByName("canvas")[0].children[0].children[1];
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.context.on('drawing', data => this.onDrawingEvent(data))
  }

   onDrawingEvent(data) {
    this.drawLine(
      data.x0,
      data.y0,
      data.x1,
      data.y1,
      data.color,
      data.brushRadius,
      false,
      true,
    );
  }
  
  drawLine(x0, y0, x1, y1, color,brushRadius, emit,duplicate) {
    // Gets the offset so it fits to any window size
    var canvasTopPosition = document.getElementsByName("canvas")[0].offsetTop;
    var canvasLeftPosition = document.getElementsByName("canvas")[0].offsetLeft;
    // If Duplicate is false, it will draw on both monitors and cause duplication.
    if(duplicate)
    {
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(x0, y0);
      context.lineTo(x1, y1);
      context.strokeStyle = color;
      context.lineWidth = brushRadius * 2;
      context.lineCap = 'round';
      context.stroke();
      context.closePath();
    }
      if (!emit) {
        return;
      }
      this.context.emit('drawing', {
        x0: x0 - canvasLeftPosition,
        y0: y0 - canvasTopPosition,
        x1: x1 - canvasLeftPosition,
        y1: y1 - canvasTopPosition,
        color: color,
        brushRadius : this.state.brushRadius,
        type: this.state.usingType,
        globalCompositeOperation: context.globalCompositeOperation,
        message_type: "draw"
      });   
  }
  onMouseDown = (e) => {
    drawing = true;
    current.x = e.clientX || e.touches[0].clientX;
    current.y = e.clientY || e.touches[0].clientY;
  };

  onMouseUp = (e) => {
    if (!drawing) {
      return;
    }
    drawing = false;
    this.drawLine(
      current.x,
      current.y,
      e.clientX,
      e.clientY,
      this.state.brushColor,
      this.state.brushRadius,
      true,
      false,
    );
  };
  onMouseMove = (e) => {
    if (!drawing) {
      return;
    }
      this.drawLine(current.x, current.y, e.clientX || e.touches[0].clientX, e.clientY || e.touches[0].clientY,this.state.brushColor,this.state.brushRadius,true,false);      
      current.x = e.clientX || e.touches[0].clientX;
      current.y = e.clientY || e.touches[0].clientY;
  };


  render() {
    return (
        <div
          name="canvas"
          onMouseDown={this.onMouseDown}
          onMouseUp={this.onMouseUp}
          onMouseMove={this.onMouseMove}
          onMouseLeave={() => drawing = false} // Determines if the mouse is outside the div
        >
          <DrawableCanvas
          />
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Drawing;
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require("http");
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const socket = require("socket.io");

const io = socket(server, {
  cors: true,
});
app.use(cors());




io.on('connection', onConnection);

function onConnection(socket){
  socket.on('drawing', (data) => socket.broadcast.emit('drawing', data));
}

server.listen(port, () => console.log('server is running on port 5000'));
```

**socket.js**

```
import io from "socket.io-client";
import React from 'react';

const SOCKET_URL = "http://localhost:5000";
export const socket = io.connect(SOCKET_URL, { secure: true });
export const SocketContext = React.createContext(socket);
```

Comment: Hi Ran, maybe try another approach here and let the man draw and save the data and send it when the drawing ends? I'm telling this cause as I understand the situation from this example it simply cannot catch the speed and you are getting circles instead of a straight line. I actually don't have any idea how to implement something that holds the data and send it to broadcast but maybe that could work more eased :)

Comment: Hi Halil, If I send it when the drawing ends, it won't draw on man's 2 screen in the same time as man 1 draws only when "onmouseup" which kind of ruins the collaborative whiteboard idea. :)

Comment: Yea I know I know maybe then debounce the sending function?

Comment: Didn't work, edited the drawline function instead of this.context.emit, to   `this.SendDrawing(x0,y0,x1,y1,color)`                                                                          and sendDrawing function                                                        
`SendDrawing = debounce((x0,y0,x1,y1,color) => {
this.context.emit('drawing', {x0: x0 ,y0: y0,x1: x1,y1: y1 ,color: color, brushRadius :this.state.brushRadius,type:this.state.usingType,message_type: "draw"});   },2)`                  or any other timing